# How to get bandwidth from Wi-Fi / Mobile data to my app

Tags: android, service, background-process, android-wifi, bandwidth

How to get bandwidth from Wi-Fi / Mobile data to my app .

I want to call a background service in my application but it takes too much time to call . I want to get mobile data bandwidth and share maximum bandwidth to my app .

Please help me out if anyone knows anything about it .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One particular application should not hack the bandwidth at the cost of blocking the bandwidth from other apps. IMO, that would be illegit. I would suggest you to read more about how your application can handle slow network speed.

Just from a technical perspective, you can do that by blocking other applications consume the bandwidth but your application would require more permissions to do so such as other firewall applications.

Comment: Thanks @Vishal but how to blocking other applications consume the bandwidth you have any idea about it ???

Comment: It's a little-detailed topic. There are open source application for this which you can read and use. AFWall+ does what you want to and has it's source code open source.
https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/tree/beta/aFWall/src/main/java